# Click tracking with Doubleclick Click Tracker Tag

Tags: html, ads, double-click, click-tracking

I have a click tracker tag which is something like

```
http://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/clk/27406XXXX;10700XXXX;v?https://www.XYZ.com/
```

My question is if I change/update the click-through URL in the tag like

```
http://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/clk/27406XXXX;10700XXXX;v?https://www.ABC.com/
```

will it still track the click in the same way as it was working before updating the click-through URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Static click trackers track based on everything before the query string, and then use the URL to inform the redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to not encode the destination URL in the query string, because Google doesn't decode it and then the redirection fails.